# Spring data elasticsearch aggregate sum - price, quantity

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to aggregate data by using spring data elasticsearch. I want aggregate `sum(price)` , `sum(qty)`. What I should add to method `.addAggregation` to get that specific result and how to get it?

```
"properties": {
                        "cat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                        "curr": { "index": "not_analyzed",  "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                        "end_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                        "price": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                        "start_date": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                        "tcat": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }, 
                        "title": { "store": true,  "type": "string" }, 
                        "uid": { "store": true,  "type": "long" }
                    }
```

My service method look like:

```
final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));

        //access for many uids
        if (searchParams.getUids() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUids().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("uid", v)));
            });
        }

        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCategories() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategories().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }

        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }



    searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

            FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
            filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
            searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));
searchQuery.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders("price").field("price"));
        Aggregations aggregations = searchTemplate.query(searchQuery.build(), new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>(){
        @Override
            public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
                return response.getAggregations();
            }
        });
        return aggreg

ations.asMap();
```

Why aggregation not getting to aggregate filters, bool etc. and return aggs I thnik for all records?

Answer (score 4):

I know that it is too late, but for Spring Data Elasticsearch code from previous answer would look like this:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withIndices("index_name")
        .withTypes("type_name")
        .withQuery(searchQuery)
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_of_price").field("price"))
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_of_qty").field("qty")).build();

Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
  @Override
  public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
    return response.getAggregations();
  }
});

Sum aggregation = aggregations.get("sum_of_price");
double priceTotal = aggregation.getValue());
```

Comment: You forgot to call build() at the end of the NativeSearchQueryBuilder. It fails otherwise.

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you! Updated post with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add Aggregation and fetch the results:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = elasticsearchTemplate.client.prepareSearch("index_name")
            .setIndices("index_name")
            .setTypes("type_name").setQuery(searchQuery).addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.stats("sum_of_price").field("price"))
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_of_qty").field("qty"))
    SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet()
    Integer priceTotal = (searchResponse.getAggregations().getAsMap().get("sum_of_price").getSum())
```

Comment: Ok but how implement it in spring data elasticsearch? Look @up

Comment: This is a combination of spring data ES and Java Api.. I think this should work

Comment: It doesnt work on start when try get to object .client searchTemplate not having it I`v got @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate searchTemplate; so your example not working for me and that what I add return me all sum of index

Comment: avg = 303116.9258428293m count = 4289296272, sum = 1300158299997748 it should be much less i think its return all sum etc.

Comment: where did you get elasticsearchTemplate.client?